# Unable to access redshift from local machine using VPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-vpc

I created a redshift cluster in EU region. I also created a  VPC and other artifacts including route tables with igw (using GUI with VPC and More option). Then attached this VPC to redshift cluster while creation.

However,  I’’m unable to connect with this redshift from CD or local machine. I'm using postgres CLI.
Ideally it should have worked. Any ideas?

I'm able to connect from query editor from AWS Redshift console

*Edit Troubleshooting done so far*

- This postgress command times out  `psql -h redshift-cluster-1.xxxxx.eu-west-1.redshift.amazonaws.com -U awsuser -d dev -p 5497`. postgres installation is correct. As I'm able to connect with one of other redshift installations

> psql: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
> Is the server running on host "redshift-cluster-1.xxxx.eu-west-1.redshift.amazonaws.com" (xx.xx.xx.xx) and accepting
> TCP/IP connections on port 5497?

- `dig` works but `telnet` fails

Adding describes.
**VPC**

```
{
    "Vpcs": [
        {
            "CidrBlock": "10.0.0.0/16",
            "DhcpOptionsId": "dopt-0f7cfde8258b431f5",
            "State": "available",
            "VpcId": "vpc-0a673f3e2399e0904",
            "OwnerId": "xx",
            "InstanceTenancy": "default",
            "CidrBlockAssociationSet": [
                {
                    "AssociationId": "vpc-cidr-assoc-0f738813e1a319934",
                    "CidrBlock": "10.0.0.0/16",
                    "CidrBlockState": {
                        "State": "associated"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "IsDefault": false,
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "test-vpc"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Security Groups**

```
{
    "SecurityGroups": [
        {
            "Description": "default VPC security group",
            "GroupName": "default",
            "IpPermissions": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "-1",
                    "IpRanges": [],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": [],
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [
                        {
                            "GroupId": "sg-07c16a51da213b9a8",
                            "UserId": "xx"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "OwnerId": "xx",
            "GroupId": "sg-07c16a51da213b9a8",
            "IpPermissionsEgress": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "-1",
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": [],
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": []
                }
            ],
            "VpcId": "vpc-0a673f3e2399e0904"
        },
        {
            "Description": "SG1",
            "GroupName": "SG1",
            "IpPermissions": [
                {
                    "FromPort": 5497,
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "IpRanges": [
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "52.27.190.0/23"
                        },
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "64.39.96.0/20"
                        },
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "10.189.32.85/32"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": [],
                    "PrefixListIds": [
                        {
                            "PrefixListId": "pl-6fa54006"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ToPort": 6000,
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": []
                }
            ],
            "OwnerId": "xxxxx",
            "GroupId": "sg-0fccd6f7706900e54",
            "IpPermissionsEgress": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "-1",
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": [],
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": []
                }
            ],
            "VpcId": "vpc-0a673f3e2399e0904"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Redshift cluster**

```
{
    "Clusters": [
        {
            "ClusterIdentifier": "redshift-cluster-1",
            "NodeType": "dc2.large",
            "ClusterStatus": "available",
            "ClusterAvailabilityStatus": "Available",
            "MasterUsername": "awsuser",
            "DBName": "dev",
            "Endpoint": {
                "Address": "redshift-cluster-1.xxx.eu-west-1.redshift.amazonaws.com",
                "Port": 5497
            },
            "ClusterCreateTime": "2022-08-09T14:51:58.527000+00:00",
            "AutomatedSnapshotRetentionPeriod": 1,
            "ManualSnapshotRetentionPeriod": -1,
            "ClusterSecurityGroups": [],
            "VpcSecurityGroups": [
                {
                    "VpcSecurityGroupId": "sg-07c16a51da213b9a8",
                    "Status": "active"
                },
                {
                    "VpcSecurityGroupId": "sg-0fccd6f7706900e54",
                    "Status": "active"
                }
            ],
            "ClusterParameterGroups": [
                {
                    "ParameterGroupName": "default.redshift-1.0",
                    "ParameterApplyStatus": "in-sync"
                }
            ],
            "ClusterSubnetGroupName": "cluster-subnet-group-1",
            "VpcId": "vpc-0a673f3e2399e0904",
            "AvailabilityZone": "eu-west-1a",
            "PreferredMaintenanceWindow": "mon:03:30-mon:04:00",
            "PendingModifiedValues": {},
            "ClusterVersion": "1.0",
            "AllowVersionUpgrade": true,
            "NumberOfNodes": 2,
            "PubliclyAccessible": true,
            "Encrypted": false,
            "ClusterPublicKey": "<>",
            "ClusterNodes": [
                {
                    "NodeRole": "LEADER",
                    "PrivateIPAddress": "10.0.2.114",
                    "PublicIPAddress": "52.208.40.55"
                },
                {
                    "NodeRole": "COMPUTE-0",
                    "PrivateIPAddress": "10.0.6.171",
                    "PublicIPAddress": "46.51.199.140"
                },
                {
                    "NodeRole": "COMPUTE-1",
                    "PrivateIPAddress": "10.0.8.205",
                    "PublicIPAddress": "18.200.92.114"
                }
            ],
            "ClusterRevisionNumber": "40496",
            "Tags": [],
            "EnhancedVpcRouting": false,
            "IamRoles": [],
            "MaintenanceTrackName": "current",
            "ElasticResizeNumberOfNodeOptions": "[4]",
            "DeferredMaintenanceWindows": [],
            "NextMaintenanceWindowStartTime": "2022-08-15T03:30:00+00:00",
            "AvailabilityZoneRelocationStatus": "disabled",
            "ClusterNamespaceArn": "<>",
            "TotalStorageCapacityInMegaBytes": 800000,
            "AquaConfiguration": {
                "AquaStatus": "disabled",
                "AquaConfigurationStatus": "auto"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What are the security groups for the cluster?

Comment: There are two SGs
1. default and 2. is custom TCP which includes my IP in source column

Comment: I even added my exact IP also as one of the inbound-rules

Comment: I assume you configured Redshift to use the non-default port number?

Comment: You have to edit the question, and provide **details** of all the rules in the SGs.

Comment: Why does your command reference port `5497`, but the error message mentions port `549`? Amazon Redshift uses port `5439` by default, so what port is configured in your Redshift cluster?

Comment: Added describe results for VPC, SG and Cluster. `549` was typo it is `5497`. Default `5439` is blocked allowed port is `5497`